# Trouble declaring an adjacency list in C

Tags: c

It's the very first time I am trying to use a adjacency list and I am really confused with its declaration

This is my node structure and the list for using as my first node, what I called head

```
typedef struct node
{
    int NodeNum;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct list
{
    node *head;
}list;
```

and here is where I try to allocate the correct amount of memory for the array of heads that the user wants

```
int n;

scanf("%d", &n);

list *NodList[n] = {0};

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    NodList[i] = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    NodList[i]->head = NULL;
}
```

Here is the thing, I want the user to tell me how many nodes I'll have and then allocate the correct amount of memory for it, but apparently I am getting something wrong here

Comment: What is the definition of `vertice`?

Comment: Do you want it to be a VLA or allocated? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Comment: @user3386109 sorry, vertice is node in my language, forgot only to translate that part

Comment: An array of the struct `list` can be created with `list NodList[n] = {{0}};` Then you just need to create the linked lists of `struct node`.

Comment: i'm surprised this even compiles:  you cannot declare an array of node pointers with a non constant variable. if you want to report the length of a linked list, you either need to maintain a global counter that is inc/dec by the inserter/deleter, or walk the list.

Comment: @PeterT [Variable length arrays (VLAs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) were added to C in C99 (and still exist, but are optional in C11). Both gcc and clang support VLAs for C code (and allow them as an extension for C++). Not sure about MS. So you *can* declare an array of node pointers with a non-constant size, if you use the right compiler. But there's no need to use an a array of pointers when you can just declare the array of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a little bit on Antonin GAVREL's answer. Basically using the same linked list he brought up, and introducing an AListEntry used to represent the adjacency list. Each AListEntry points to a vertex and that vertex's adjacent vertices. It also points to the next AListEntry.

You could, instead, also just replace the AListEntry with a dynamically allocated array of Node pointers if you know the number of vertices ahead of time. Each index in the array will correspond to a vertex, and the pointer will point to the head Node pointer of your adjacent vertices for that vertex, which will a linked list. You'll end up with an array of linked lists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node* next;
} t_Node;

t_Node* createNode(int value)
{
    t_Node* node = (t_Node*)malloc(sizeof(t_Node));
    node->value = value;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

t_Node* addNode(int value, t_Node* node)
{
    node->next = createNode(value);
    return node->next;
}

typedef struct AListEntry
{
    t_Node* vertex;
    t_Node* adjacentVertices;
    struct AListEntry* next;
} t_AListEntry;

t_AListEntry* createAListEntry(
    t_Node* vertex, 
    t_Node* adjacentVertices)
{
    t_AListEntry* entry = (t_AListEntry*)malloc(sizeof(t_AListEntry));
    entry->vertex = vertex;
    entry->adjacentVertices = adjacentVertices;
    entry->next = NULL;
    return entry;
}

void printAListEntries(t_AListEntry* aList)
{
    while (aList != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> [ ", aList->vertex->value);
        
        t_Node* node = aList->adjacentVertices;
        while (node != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d ", node->value);
            node = node->next;
        }
        
        printf("]\n");
        
        aList = aList->next;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    t_Node* v1 = createNode(1);
    
    t_Node* v1Adjacents = createNode(2);
    addNode(3, v1Adjacents);
    
    t_AListEntry* aList = createAListEntry(v1, v1Adjacents);
    
    t_Node* v2 = createNode(2);
    
    t_Node* v2Adjacents = createNode(1);
    addNode(3, v2Adjacents);
    
    aList->next = createAListEntry(v2, v2Adjacents);
    
    t_Node* v3 = createNode(3);
    
    t_Node* v3Adjacents = createNode(1);
    addNode(2, v3Adjacents);
    
    aList->next->next = createAListEntry(v3, v3Adjacents);
    
    printAListEntries(aList);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hey man thanks, that was What I needed, apreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Example where the array is declared on the stack as a VLA:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct  Node
{
    int         value;
    struct Node *next;
}               t_Node;


bool build_linked_list(t_Node **head, int n) {
    t_Node *node;
    t_Node *tmp;

    static int a = 1024; // just for test purposes
    if (!(node = (t_Node*)malloc(sizeof(t_Node))))
        return false;
    node->value = a;
    *head = node;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!(tmp = (t_Node*)malloc(sizeof(t_Node))))
             return false;
        tmp->value = i + a;
        node->next = tmp;
        node = tmp;

    }

    a <<= 1; // so that other nodes have different values

    return true;
}


int main(void) {
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    t_Node *nodes[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         if (!build_linked_list(&nodes[i], n)) {
            perror("Failed to malloc node");
            return 1;
         }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (nodes[i]) {
            printf("%d\n", nodes[i]->value);
            nodes[i] = nodes[i]->next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Let me know if you have any question

Comment: I think he was going for an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), which can be used to represent a graph: "An implementation suggested by Guido van Rossum uses a hash table to associate each vertex in a graph with an array of adjacent vertices." Just create a hash table, and add an entry for each vertex, where the key is the `NodeNum` and the value is a linked list of vertices adjacent to it.

Comment: it needs to be an array cause as @Alex Riveron said I am trying to work with a graph, long story short I need an array of the structure List, that I declared

Comment: see my edit, this is an array of linked list, as per Cormen et al. definition